# Page redirection after logout in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

While login into the mvc application I have the following url as

> http://localhost:51495/Account/Login/ClientA

Where ClientA is the name of the client.

My issue is after logoff I am not getting the exact URL which was shown at time of login. However, I am able to log off and return to login page successfully.

Below url is displayed after logoff

> http://localhost:51495/

my logoff code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOff()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation(4, "User logged out.");

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(this.Login), "Account");
    }
```

So what I need to do to get the same url which is shown at the time of login?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37022067/181087). Although it is about prior versions of MVC, the concepts have not changed in MVC core. You need an action filter to handle the redirects automatically regardless of what URL the user is on - this is not a concern you should put into your controllers.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for the help !