# Change route to username after registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, attributerouting

I have followed the correct answer marked for this thread [How to change route to username after logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996021/how-to-change-route-to-username-after-logged-in) and my requirement is exactly what the question says. However when I register a new user (I am using username instead of email) the redirection doesn't follow my custom route.

For instance, when I register with username = Janet, the URL looks like `localhost/?username=Janet` 
and throws an error. But if I manually remove the "/?username=" and keep `localhost/Janet` then it shows the landing page of my application.

I have tried to play with return `RedirectToAction("Index","Home");` of my register post method but no luck.

Can someone help in this and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Route config

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Username_Default",
                url: "{username}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { username = new OwinUsernameConstraint() }
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Username constraint

```
    public class OwinUsernameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        private object synclock = new object();

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (parameterName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parameterName");
            if (values == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

            object value;
            if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value) && value != null)
            {
                string valueString = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                return this.GetUsernameList(httpContext).Contains(valueString);
            }
            return false;
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetUsernameList(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            string key = "UsernameConstraint.GetUsernameList";
            var usernames = httpContext.Cache[key];
            if (usernames == null)
            {
                lock (synclock)
                {
                    usernames = httpContext.Cache[key];
                    if (usernames == null)
                    {
                        // Retrieve the list of usernames from the database
                        using (var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
                        {
                            usernames = (from users in db.Users
                                            select users.UserName).ToList();
                        }

                        httpContext.Cache.Insert(
                            key: key,
                            value: usernames,
                            dependencies: null,
                            absoluteExpiration: Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                            slidingExpiration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                            priority: CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                            onRemoveCallback: null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return (IEnumerable<string>)usernames;
        }
    }
```

Register controller

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: Edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: Do you also have the `RedirectLoggedOnUserFilter` as per the answer you linked to? And are you saying that your `RedirectToAction("Index","Home");` in the `Register()` method is generating `localhost/?username=Janet`?

Comment: yes I do have the `RedirectLoggedOnUserFilter` which a replica of the code updated in the linked answer. And yes, on successful registration the generated URL is `localhost/?username=Janet`

Comment: Can't test that code at the moment although it looks correct. Suggest you put a break-point on the first line of that method and step through it.

Comment: Strangely when I debug the code runs ok :

Comment: The moment I remove the breakpoints it goes back to the situation that I have described here.

Comment: Seems odd, and I can't see from your code how `username` could be added as a query string value. Just as a side note, if you only have a few controllers, you might consider creating specific routes - e.g.  `url: "{username}/Product/{action}/{id}" for each so that you don't need the route constraint (you would still need the `RedirectLoggedOnUserFilter`). It might give better performance if you have a lot of users.

Comment: I cannot repeat what you claiming, but I suspect the issue is the order in which you doing this. There is a problem with the code you linked to because the `GetUsernameList()` checks if `usernames` is `null` and the first time it is called (the very first request you make), it will be populated with existing users. When you add a new user in the `Register()` method, that user is not in the `usernames` collection because you do not update it anywhere so the route constraint fails and you hit the `Default` route which does not have a parameter for `username` so its added as a query string.

Comment: You will need to add the user name to the cached collection before your `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");`

Comment: So how do I do that. Because when I debug, I could see the collection is updated and the routing happens fine. I don't understand why it messes up itself when I remove the breakpoints.

Comment: It may be a timing issue when your in debug mode (because of the `slidingExpiration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),` setting - so after 15 sec, the cache is cleared and the database is called again and you 'new' user name now exists in the cache)

Comment: Perhaps to test, just comment out the `if (usernames == null)` line of code so that `usernames` will always be populated from the database and see if that solves the issue of adding the query string value in normal mode.

Comment: No change. I have uploaded the files here https://www.dropbox.com/s/n11twubaewk3ra7/MvcUsernameInUrl-master%20%282%29.zip?dl=0

Comment: Anything I could try beyond the above possibilities?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change route to username after logged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996021/how-to-change-route-to-username-after-logged-in)

Comment: @NightOwl888 yes I am following your demo only, however, the registration process is not working as I want. The issue has been elaborated in the question. Any help?