# MVC Application Username in route upon login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Upon login I want to re route to a new page. (Example: mysite.com/Dashboard/User/Username)

I also want it to verify that user is logged in before it allows access to said URL.

I'm new to MVC and C# and appreciate your help.

My controller: *What do I pass into the controller to make it work?*

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult User()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Route.config.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserNameRoute",
            url: "{username}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "User", username = "" }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change route to username after logged in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996021/how-to-change-route-to-username-after-logged-in)

Comment: @NightOwl888 That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserNameRoute",
    url: "Dashboard/User/{username}",
    defaults: new { username = "" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I chose not to put the `{controller}` and `{action}` placeholders in the template as that would make it equal to the default route template. You could of course use just the action template if that is what you need:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "UserNameRoute",
    url: "Dashboard/{action}/{username}",
    defaults: new { action = "User", username = "" }
);
```

Also note I put it before the default route because it is more specific. Otherwise the default route would catch every request.

*Authorization* is something you can't do here however. You will need to do that by e.g. creating a custom AuthorizeAttribute subclass that checks the username matches the logged in user.

Comment: `[Authorize]` isn't enough. That will only verify that *some user is logged in*, not necessarily the same user as specified in the URL. The OP will need a custom `[Authorize]` attribute that adds a check for that. Also, you should add sample code for how to redirect to that new route after the user signs in, since I think the OP doesn't know how to do that either.

Comment: I probably asked too much. I think I need to pass something into the following for the username to be passed through the controller, but not sure what:

        public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult User()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

Comment: Your action needs a string parameter called username.